# OData fails to serialize model with constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to enable nullable reference types in my project and followed the model [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) provided by the EF Core team. But it breaks model creation in OData.

Nullable reference types are enabled by putting this in the `.csproj` file

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

I'm using

- netcoreapp3.1
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData Version="7.4.0-beta"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="3.1.3"

My model looks like this

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog(int id, string name, string author)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

When I try to POST to the endpoint

```
[Route("odata/[controller]s")]
public class BlogController : ODataController
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public BlogController(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get() {...}

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Blog blog) {...}
}
```

Payload:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "foo",
    "author": "bar"
}
```

Then the `blog` parameter is `null`.

If I turn off "nullable reference types" and remove the constructor it works.

Please advice.

**Startup**

Perhaps I should mention that I'm using the new endpoints API in ASPNET Core 3.1 and just added support for in OData v7.4.0-beta

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "..\\frontend\\dist";
        });

        services.AddOData();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        var model = EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel(); // EnableLowerCamelCase = true

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(50);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model);
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "..\\frontend";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**
I believe the problem boils down to OData not supporting models with constructors, even though Json.Net supports it out of the box.

Comment: @mjwills nullable reference types dictates the need for the constructor. Also added the payload to the question

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to POST to the endpoint with Payload:
>
> {
>       "id": 123,
>       "name": "foo",
>       "author": "bar"
>   }
>
> Then the `blog` parameter is `null`

In [this github issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1677#issuecomment-439174553), we can find: *it doesn't support case insensitive in the payload content.*

And to make it can handle above payload well, as you mentioned, we can turn off "nullable reference types", and then modify the code like below.

*In Blog class*

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {

    }
    public Blog(int id, string name, string author)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

and configure `ODataConventionModelBuilder` with [`EnableLowerCamelCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.builder.odataconventionmodelbuilderextensions.enablelowercamelcase?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0).

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder()
    .EnableLowerCamelCase();
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that `EnableLowerCamelCase` is on

Comment: Yes, so I include that in above post.

Comment: This entire problem stemmed from turning on "nullable reference types", I'd like to keep it on. Any suggestions regarding that?